# Reading a website using C# Agility Pack from a proxied server application hosted in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, proxy

I am creating an **ASP.NET MVC 4** website that retrieves offers from other sites and aggregates their content in my website. (Basically, it's just food offers for me and some work friends to use when we go out to lunch.)

I am using [Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-agility-pack/info) to read the websites as follows:

```
HtmlWeb webget = new HtmlWeb();
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://my-proxy.proxy.proxy.proxy:<port>"), true);
wp.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

var doc = webget.Load(url, "GET", wp,
    System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```

Running in **Visual Studio** it works. But when i run it from **IIS**, I get the following error:

> ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved. The following error
>   was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: **access denied**. Access
>   control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this
>   time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is
>   incorrect. Your administrator of the cache is generated Tue, 25 Nov
>   2014 12:22:30 GMT by proxy Address (squid).

Note that I have configured my web application with an ASP.NET v4.0 application pool.

Is there anything missing from my code?

Comment: Looks like the IIS user does not have permission to access the internet via your proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Identity of the Application pool does not have the required permission to access the proxy server.

You can either set the identity of  your application pool to a user that would have permissions, or set the identity of a user within the code.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://foo.bar/file.doc");
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```